# Projection of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Compute $:$ $proj_\vec y (\vec x)$ $\vec{x}_1=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}, \vec{y}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Since the projection would be $:$ $(-2/0) * \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

and you can't divide by 0.

Does that conclude that there isn't a projection of $:$ $\vec x$ on $\vec y$?

Comment: How are you calculating that $0$?

Comment: @MichaelBiro 1+(-1) from $:$ $\vec y$

Comment: The formula for the projection of the vector $\vec u$ onto the subspace $\operatorname{span}(\vec w)$ is given by $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{span}(\vec w)}\vec u = \dfrac {\langle \vec w, \vec u\rangle}{\langle \vec w, \vec w\rangle}\vec w$, where $\langle a, b\rangle = b^T a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the denominator should be the square of the norm of $\vec y$, which is guaranteed to be strictly positive (since $\vec y \neq \vec 0$). It is the dot product of $\vec y$ with itself:
$$
\| \vec y \|^2 = \vec y \cdot \vec y = 1^2 + 0^2 + (-1)^2 + 0^2 = 2
$$

Comment: Oh I misunderstood how to calculate the projection...thanks for the information!